# Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, xml, facebook

I'm having errors that didn't showed yesterday, when i tested.

This is my some part of log cat error.

```
 Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.

                                                     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
                                                     at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
                                                     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                     at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:69)
                                                     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:201)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
```

This is the login_xml

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="  connect_with_facebook"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

And this is the login_activity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);



        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
```

Comment: Can anybody knows what problem is??

Comment: refer to below links 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735572/error-inflating-class-com-facebook-widget-loginbutton-with-facebook-sdk-4-0-1 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570800/issues-creating-login-button-using-facebook-sdk-4-1-2

Comment: did you try this You have to use FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ???

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialized Facebook SDK.

```
 @Override 
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); 

            loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            }
```

Comment: This is not the answer.