# When I add the facebook login button in the xml, it said missing style

Tags: android, xml, facebook

I am trying to add the facebook login button to the xml. Unfortunaltely, the UI page show me the error message is

> "Missing styles.Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?"

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Comment: Did you add facebook to your manifest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045307/how-to-integrate-facebook-in-android-using-facebook-sdk-4-10/30047309#30047309

Comment: When i restart the eclipse, i can see the button image in my xml. Thanks for help.